# Remote desktop connection error: No CVE-2018-0886 under 20H2?

Tags: remote-desktop

Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing.

[image: screenshot]

And here the error as text:

> An authentication error has occurred. The function requested is not
> supported
>
> Remote computer: [computer name]
>
> This could be due to CredSSP
> encryption oracle remediation. For more information, see
> https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660

I have two Windows 10 devices each with version 20H2. So according to https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/de-de/vulnerability/CVE-2018-8141 it should be fixed since 1909. What KB would you recommend to install to resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you edit the post to include the actual text of the error. I was not able to find what I was looking for in CVE 2018 0886.  I am using Windows 10 21H1 and RDP works without error to another 21H1 machine, a Kali Machine and an Ubuntu machine. So I cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: "What KB would you recommend to install to resolve the issue?" - The current cumulative update for the version of Windows 10 you are running.  According to the vulnerability, 2004, isn't even vulnerable only 1709 was vulnerable.  This particular exploit would have been patch 4 years ago.

Comment: Hey @John I did include the error as picutre. However I have too low rep to embed the picture

Comment: @Ramhound yeah.. thats what I'm confused about

Comment: Please see if this article helps you.   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently it looks like I tried all the time with the IP-Address while I'm only able to connect via FQDN. I assume this is might some GPO taking place. If someone could explain what GPO please edit!